# Логистическая регрессия, алгоритм работы

Tags: машинное-обучение, регрессия

Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я понял алгоритм.

Вот [ссылка](https://dropmefiles.com/A9UIz) на методичку откуда я брал формулы.

Вот как я понял:

1. Первый столбец в БД (который отвечает за то умер человек или нет) это `y`, остальные 6 и один фиктивный признак в начале, это вектор `x`.
2. Из формулы [image: формлу1] я получаю новый вектор `θ^T = [θ0, θ1, ... θ6]`
3. В формуле[image: формула2] `N = 887`, кол-во человек. Как я понял вся БД будет использована под обучающую выборку, было бы лучше 850 записей под обучение и например 27 под тестовую выборку?

   `yi` это элементы вектора `y`.

   Запись `e^(θ^T*xi)` означает: константа `e` в степени вектор `θ^T` скалярно умноженный на вектор `Xi`, где `Xi` это вектор `x`, для `i`-того человека.

   И как я понял, это формула нужна лишь для того, чтобы потом найти её градиент.
4. Начальный вектор `θ0`, если я правильно понимаю, это вектор из 7 начальных коэффициентов, которые я могу сгенерировать случайно. (В каком только диапазоне? [0, 1]? [0.4, 0.6]?)
5. `μt` - это шаг, который можно подобрать тренируя сеть, чтобы она быстрей обучалась, но изначально присвоить ему маленькое значение, например `0.01`.
6. Прогоняю через функцию градиента всю обучающую выборку `t` раз (где `t` кол-во эпох). В итоге, что я должен наблюдать? Что должно стремится к максимуму/минимуму?

Если я совсем не правильно понял алгоритм, можете пожалуйста объяснить простым языком или скинуть ссылку на какой-нибудь ресурс.

Comment: Во-первых, приведенная ссылка не работает. Во-вторых: да, лучше всю выборку разбить на обучающую и тестовую части. После построения модели -  проверять ее качество надо  на тестовой выборке. В третьих: Начальные значения выбираете произвольные. (Откуда взялись 0.4 и 0.6 -  непонятно). В четвертых: минимизировать вы должны ошибку между результатом, который можно получить по вашей модели и результатами, которые вам даны в  выборке.

Comment: @passant 1) хмм странно. [Вот](https://wdfiles.ru/3987f2) скинул на другой файлообменник 2) 0.4 и 0.6 я просто предположил, что может надо брать значения в районе 0.5 3) Я из методички не совсем понял, что именно возвращает результат. И где функция минимизации в методичке, если она вообще там есть.

Comment: Ну как-же, написано же: "Наша цель - найти параметр θ, который лучше всего объясняет наши обучающие примеры. Таким образом мы должны найти наилучшую целевую функцию в семействе функций, зависящих от
параметра". А на картинке этот самый l(ф) и его дельта явно показаны. И вы ищете минимум функции (возможно локальный) который будет в точке, гда эта самая дельта становиться равной (близкой) нулю.

Comment: @passant хах, логично. Получается алгоритм такой: нахожу `PX = log (θ * x)`, рассчитываю результат `l(θ) = сумма log ( (1/(1 + e^-PX)) ^ Y * (1/(1 + e^PX)) ^ (1 - Y) )`, далее рассчитываю дельту `▽l(θ) = сумма ( (Y - 1/(1 + e^PX)) * X)` и последний этап, изменяю коэффициенты `θ(t+1) = θ(t) + μt * ▽l(θ)`. При этом `θ(0)` = случайные значения от 0 до 1. Скажите пожалуйста я правильно все понял? И последний вопросик, в коде правильней реализовывать расчеты при помощи операций над векторами/матрицами или отдельно для каждого `X[i]` например рассчитывать изменение коэффициентов?

Comment: "в коде правильней реализовывать расчеты при помощи..." тех средств, которыми лучше владеете. (Если нет учебных ограничений). Причем это зависит и от языка, который используете. В Python есть numpy для матричных вычислений, есть готовые реализации градиентного спуска в sklearn. А можно и на чистом Python (правда не уверен, что так будет быстрее и точно будет сложнее).

Comment: @passant я имел в виду, что по идее если делать через операции с матрицами, то например для `X[0]`, `X[1]` и т.д. веса изменятся в 1 момент, а если сделать цикл по наборам, то после `X[0]` веса изменятся и будут использоваться уже при расчете `X[1]`. Или это не влияет ни на что?

Comment: если код писать правильно, но никаких "побочных явлений" не произойдет. Ну а если понимания "как правильно" нет, тогда лучше пользоваться более простыми средствами, которые возьмут всю рутину на себя

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131706/discussion-between-bonifacy-and-passant).